# Mongodb sort on conditional clause

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I want to do something like this:-

```
db.pub_pairs.find({status:'active'})
            .sort( { if (pcat="abc") then 0 else 1 end })
            .limit(10)
```

In other words, I want it to prefer records where the field pcat is `"abc"`.
I also need it to be fast, but I can add indexes as necessary.
Any suggestions on how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Why not make the `pcat="abc"` part of your find statement?

Answer (score 0):

A decently efficient way of doing that would be to query the DB twice. Once for documents having `pcat="abc"` and once (if needed) for documents having `pcat!="abc"`

Something along the lines of (pseudo-code):

```
var data = db.pub_pairs.find({status:'active', pcat="abc"})
                       .limit(10)
if (data.length < 10)
  data.concat(db.pub_pairs.find({status:'active', pcat!="abc"})
                          .limit(10-data.length))
```

For this to perform well, I would suggest a compound index on `{status: 1, pcat: 1}`

Please note, [like any other "find" with MongoDB, you have to be prepared to retrieve the same document *twice* in the result set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#cursor-isolation), notably here if the `pcat` field was concurrently modified by an other client during execution.